# seleniumwire blank response.reason

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, seleniumwire

Status code prints correct, but reason always blank. Whats wrong?
I need output like this:

```
status: 200 (OK)
```

but got this:

```
status: 200 ()
```

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver 

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0'

def my_response_interceptor(request, response): 
    print("status: " + str(response.status_code) + " (" + response.reason + ")")
    print(response.headers)

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.response_interceptor = my_response_interceptor

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('site')
```